# Why can't a docker container call another container with a fully qualified domain name? (Instead of localhost)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers running on my development machine.  When I run them they both load in a browser when I use my computer name in the URL:

```
http://my-computer.mydomain.net:48681/my-app-one
http://my-computer.mydomain.net:47612/my-app-two
```

When I try to call *my-app-two* from *my-app-one* using the above URL, I get the following error:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Name or service not known

This is the error that you usually get when you use localhost in the URL.  Using `localhost` errors out because `localhost` is seen from the container's point of view, not the hosting dev machine.

But when I use a full URL I don't see why it would not work.  It works fine loading some other URL that is a text page not hosted in Docker.

**Why does docker not like me to call another container with a fully qualified URL?**

NOTE: I am familiar with Docker Compose, and could set this up in there if needed, but I want to understand this issue rather than just move to Docker Compose.

NOTE 2: I can also make this work using an IP address.  But again, I want to use the name of my host in the url (or at least understand why it does not work).

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, this isn't a container issue at all. To explain this in full would mean teaching you a lot about the way networks and domain name resolution works. But, at the most basic level, the container has no way of resolving the hostname you've given it in the URL. You need to either set up the hostname in etc/hosts or you need to configure a dns server that can resolve that name to an IP address. Docker-compose can help solve this problem, but you're solving the wrong problem.

You should be moving on from layer 3 routing (`address:port`) to layer 7 routing (`/service`). You should be thinking about addressing a service rather than a machine, otherwise you're losing quite a lot of the benefits of using containers in the first place.

Comment: Why does have no way of resolving the host name for my own computer?  It can resolve the host name of my machines on my network just fine.  It seems to only be when it needs to resolve the host name that is my dev machine.  Is there something special with my host name when compare with all the other host names?

Comment: I'm guessing that by 'my development machine' you mean your desktop or laptop computer. These are rarely directly addressable in this way on corporate networks because they aren't considered servers. If you actually meant that your dev machine is a network server then my answer is bollox and this should actually work :)